# What different two dimensional array?

Tags: solidity

What different two dimensional array?

```
uint[5][] ipadPrice;
uint[][5] macPrice;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `uint[5][] ipadPrice`, the first dimension is `[5]`, which is fixed (only 5 elements can be stored here), while the second dimension is `[]`, which is dynamic.

For `uint[][5] macPrice`, the first dimension is `[]`, which is dynamic, while the second dimension is `[5]`, which is fixed (only 5 elements can be stored here).

You can stored an arbitrary number of elements in a dynamic dimension.

Both of your examples are called mixed-sized two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

The notation `[]` means that the array has dynamic length - its length is not preset. Therefore the first array is a two-dimensional array where the first dimension has dynamic length and the second has 5 elements. The second array is other way around.

Dynamic length means that there can be any amount of entries in the array. Specifying `[5]` means there are exactly 5 entries.